# Drop-down lists for contact form

Tags: html, css, contact-form

Is there a way to add an additional 'submenu' to a dropdown list on a contact form? So it would technically work like a drop-down navigation.

Below is the drop-down list for my contact form. And i've been asked to see if I can add additional options to lets say, Existing Partner. So when they hover over that item it expands to other options.

```
<label for="hear">How did you hear about us?  </label>
            <select class="contact-drop-down"  name="hear" id="hear">
                <option>Click to choose</option>
                <option value="1">Existing Partner</option>
                <option value="2">Word of mouth</option>
                <option value="3">Brochure</option>
                <option value="4">Email mailshot</option>
                <option value="5">Google</option>
                <option value="6">Yahoo</option>
                <option value="7">Bing</option>
                <option value="8">Other search engine</option>
                <option value="9">Other</option>
            </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't expand on hover with the standard `select` within HTML, but you can with either Javascript or HTML5 and CSS3.

[This site](http://dizyne.net/30-beautiful-html5-css3-drop-menus/) has a list of 30 examples of HTML5 navigation menus and [this site](http://www.jqueryrain.com/example/jquery-menu-example/) has a large selection of Javascript and JQuery examples.

Hopefully one of these might help you get what you want.

Comment: How would I go about implementing a dropdown menu like them into a contact form?

Comment: Your best bet for easily integrating into your contact form is a HTML5/CSS3 one. Using http://www.script-tutorials.com/css3-vertical-multicolor-3d-menu/ as an example, this is just CSS styling on top of a list. To correctly populate your form, I suppose the best thing would be to implement some JQuery to set the field on your form with the value of the menu item you clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use optgroup tag for this.

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Existing Partners">
    <option value="existing_partner_a">Partner A</option>
    <option value="existing_partner_b">Partner B</option>
    <option value="existing_partner_others">Others</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot add sub menu to actual dropdown control. But you may find many custom controls.

[Check out this](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/38-jquery-and-css-drop-down-multi-level-menu-solutions/)

Saurabh Goyal above suggested to use . I also thought of suggesting the same. But  is used for categorization & I dont think thats what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try optgroup for this .for example

```
   <select>
      <optgroup label="Swedish Cars">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="German Cars">
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      </optgroup>
</select>
```